# bcrypt mechanism in auth (no match hashes)

Tags: python, mongodb, bcrypt

i'm trying to implement a login method for mongodb , using python (pymongo) and bcrypt. the problem comes when i try to compare hashes , they always are different :$ .

This is my test code( First of all i put into mongodb an user with a password hashed ):

using pythons scrypt :

```
bcrypt.hashpw('testpassword', bcrypt.gensalt(12))
'$2a$12$K1hnCm5z74QtXaynv4.S8.i1FK9xjRr7JSPCRCyB9zpv8xZznZGFi'


db.users.insert({username: "yichuan",password: "$2a$12$K1hnCm5z74QtXaynv4.S8.i1FK9xjRr7JSPCRCyB9zpv8xZznZGFi" });
```

Once we have put it into the db , i'm trying to make the magic :D:

```
def test_connectionManagerLoginPass(self):
    connectionmanager=dbconnection.ConnectionManager()
    username='yichuan'
    password='testpassword'
    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt(12))
    self.assertIsNotNone(connectionmanager.login(username,hashed), 'No error espected in login')
```

But the problem comes when i see **hashed** value:

```
'$2a$12$hw1DaWdOf3ECBcSgu2GB4Of3oAdKvyzl0xftBVzbyqkjK2A3X.LOm'
```

**it is s totally different for wich one i have generated before!!!** . Also i have been reading
that i didn't need to save the bcrypt.gensalt(12) . So i'm a little confused.

Thanks for reading , Any help with what is wrong in my implementation of the auth?

**posdata (more code)**:

```
def login(self,username,password):
    if self.loginfieldsfilter(username,password):
        dbdata = self.users.find_one({'username': username})
        if password == dbdata[ 'password' ]:
            return True
        else:
            return None 
    else:
        return None
```

And yes , i'm sure that the db is giving me the correct fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a password check you need to pass the hash itself as the salt, as it contains the salt as a *prefix*. This is a little confusing, but since you absolutely must use the same salt to get the same hash as before, that's the only way:

```
>>> myhash = bcrypt.hashpw('testpassword', bcrypt.gensalt(12))
>>> myhash    
'$2a$12$K1hnCm5z74QtXaynv4.S8.i1FK9xjRr7JSPCRCyB9zpv8xZznZGFi'
>>> bcrypt.hashpw('testpassword', myhash)
'$2a$12$K1hnCm5z74QtXaynv4.S8.i1FK9xjRr7JSPCRCyB9zpv8xZznZGFi'
```

(but I just put this together by copy&paste)

Comment: Now i understand , but for a login , i have a problem . I need that the client make de bcrypt function , and send the hash and compare it  in the server. Would be it ok if i put a fished salt for all connection?

Comment: Your client sends you the hash and you have to compare it to the password in your database? No problem then, just compute `bcrypt.hashpw(<your_db_plaintext_pw>, <the_hash_from_your_client>)` and check if this results in the same hash the client sent you.

Comment: Ah, wait ... you don't have the plaintext pw in your db, right?

Comment: no i don't have it , then your comment is not a solution, thanks anyway . The problem comes cause server only has the hash . Then what i want the client is to send the hash that matchs it . But it seems to need the salt. Any other idea?

Comment: Hm, then maybe the client should fetch the hash from the server first in order to have the correct salt. Or you drop the requirement that the client send the hash and let him send the plaintext pw.

Comment: Mmmm , can it be better if i use the user to generate the salt?

Comment: You mean some deterministic algorithm to compute a salt from the username/email/address/etc? That would be possible, but you'd have to keep the algorithm secret in order for the salt to have any value. That's the famous "security by obscurity". ;)